# В транскрипте ссылки в цитатах некликабельны

Tags: дефект, чат

В транскрипте ссылка некликабельна, хотя в чате всё нормально. Смотреть на цитату:

> Mar 28 at 20:08, by Qwertiy

[image: В тренскрипте ссылка некликабельна]
[image: а в чате всё нормально]

Comment: А справа форма поиска налазит на кнопку «site rooms».

Comment: @СашаЧерных, у меня окно обычно максимизированное, так что не заметил это. Но вообще да :)